# How I can convert a dynamic blade content into PDF with mPDF in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mpdf

This my frontend.create-cv.pdf.blade.php :

```php
<section>

    <h1>Language</h1>

    @foreach ($data['languages'] as $lang)

        <em>{{$lang->language}} | {{$lang->language_level}}</em>

    @endforeach

</section>
```

And this is my controller :

```php
$data['languages'] = language_skill::where('jobseeker_id', $id)->get();

$mpdf->WriteHTML(view('frontend.create-cv.pdf', ['data' => $data]));
```

I'm geting this error :

> Undefined variable: data (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\rzgroup.az\resources\views\frontend\create-cv\pdf.blade.php)`

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should use PDF service provider in your controller and then pass data as array. For example:
**Controller:**

```
use PDF;

related class {
public function createPDF($data)
    {      
      $data['languages'] = language_skill::where('jobseeker_id', $id)->get();
            
      view()->share('data', $data);
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('frontend.create-cv.pdf', $data);      
      
      return $pdf->stream('pdf_output.pdf');
    }
}
```

**Route(web.php):**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\YOURController;
Route::get('/pdf', [YOURController::class, 'createPDF']);
```

Comment: ```$view = view('frontend.create-cv.pdf');
   $view->share('data', $data);
   $mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode'=>'UTF-8','format'=>'A4','autoScriptToLang'=>true,'autoLangToFont'=>true]);
   $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('frontend.create-cv.pdf', ['data' => $data]));
   $mpdf->Output(); ``` but still new error ```Method Illuminate\View\View::share does not exist.```

Comment: view without $.     view()->share('data', $data);

Comment: ```$view = View::share('data', $data);
   $mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf([ 'mode'=>'UTF8','format'=>'A4','autoScriptToLang'=>true,'autoLangToFont'=>true]);
   $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('frontend.create-cv.pdf',compact('data'))); ``` but now got another error : A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: Which version of PHP and mpdf you are using?

Comment: php 7.2.5 , mPDF 7.0

Comment: PROBLEM 3::

Console show error message following this:: "A non-numeric value encountered" at line 30648."

Someone solved this problem. My solution to solve this problem is just::

    replace mPDF->ConvertSize() function in mPDF.php file with coding from MPDF7.

            By replace function ConvertSize() with function ConvertSize() and multiplyFontSize();

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/src/SizeConverter.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML(view('frontend.create-cv.pdf', ['data' => $data]));
```

Use this:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML(view('frontend.create-cv.pdf', compact('data'));
```